How do I get Ansible to connect to a console port through an ssl console server?
I'm trying to figure out how to set up my Ansible inventory to connect to Cisco network equipment using a Blackbox Console server. The console server connects to the rs232 console port, and I can ssh (or telnet) to the console server, directly attaching to any of the equipment connected.
The problem seems to be the two step process: when connecting to a port, no output is received until you press enter or some other key, unlike ssh which presents the login prompt. I have managed to get it to work, but only when manually pressing the enter on the console to get Ansible to react. The rest of the playbook then runs.
Is there a way to make the connection a two step process? Manually sending a line feed after connection via some ssh magic despite the lack of feedback?
